# Implicit derivative with Matlab symbols

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

Is it possible to have MATLAB do implicit differentiation with its symbols? 
I have the following code

```
syms x;
y = symfun(sym('y(x)'), sym('x'));
yPrime = symfun(sym('y+(2*x)-1'), [sym('x'), sym('y')]);
diff(yPrime, x, 1)
```

From this I get

```
ans(x, y) =
2
```

but what I want to get (in some form) is

```
ans(x, y) =
dy/dx + 2
```

Is that possible?

Comment: `syms x y(x)` then `diff(y+2*x-1,x)` seems to work for me.

Comment: @David Right, that works. But my problem is that I need an extra level: `syms x y(x)`  then `yPrime = y+2x` then `diff(yPrime, x)`

Comment: OK, after `syms x y(x)` do `yPrime=y+2*x-1` then `diff(yPrime,x)`

Comment: The problem with your code was that you defined `y` as a constant `sym('y')` when you defined `yPrime`.

Comment: Ahh I figured it out. You're right, that was part of the problem. It was also because in my expression I needed it to change `sym('y+(2*x)-1')` to `sym('y(x)+(2*x)-1')` so that it knew to treat it as a function of x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you're trying to use `y` as both a symbolic variable and an abstract symbolic function ([`symfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symfun.html)), which isn't possible. A symbolic function can only take symbolic variables as arguments. I think that you can accomplish what you want with (old-style strings not needed)

```
syms y(x)        % Implicitly defines x too
yPrime = y+2*x-1 % Also a symfun because y is a symfun
diff(yPrime,x)
```

which returns this `symfun`

```
ans(x) =

diff(y(x), x) + 2
```